# Wordpress dynamic query correlating posts with products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

In WordPress, I am correlating the posts with some Woocommerce products. I have an ACF field called "code" in each post and an ACF field called "post_code" in every product. I need to display, in the single post page, under the featured image and meta of the posts all correlated products. That is, all products with "post_code"="code".
How can I do this?
I am using Elementor Pro, but other approaches (without elementor) also welcomed.

I have tried the Loop Grid of elementor, but I have found no way of doing this.